# Different behaviors between ESB 4.9.0 and 4.8.1

Tags: wso2, esb

I have this proxy service in ESB 4.8.1, when I test it with SoapUI 5.2.1. I got this problem:

1. Does not write the full log in the server console when a timeout rise, but when I change it to custom it works.
2. Does not return any response to SoapUI (payloadFactory does not work)

When I deploy it in ESB 4.9.0 it works perfectly. Its a bug from the older version? How can I fix it?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="StockQuoteProxy"
       transports="https,http"
       statistics="disable"
       trace="disable"
       startOnLoad="true">
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <send>
            <endpoint>
               <address uri="http://localhost:8089/mockStockQuoteProxySoap11Binding"
                        format="soap11">
                  <timeout>
                     <duration>1000</duration>
                     <responseAction>fault</responseAction>
                  </timeout>
                  <suspendOnFailure>
                     <errorCodes>101500,101501,101506,101507,101508</errorCodes>
                     <initialDuration>2000</initialDuration>
                     <progressionFactor>1.0</progressionFactor>
                     <maximumDuration>3000</maximumDuration>
                  </suspendOnFailure>
                  <markForSuspension>
                     <errorCodes>101504,101505</errorCodes>
                     <retriesBeforeSuspension>3</retriesBeforeSuspension>
                     <retryDelay>1</retryDelay>
                  </markForSuspension>
               </address>
            </endpoint>
         </send>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence>
         <send/>
      </outSequence>
      <faultSequence>
         <log level="full">
            <property name="FALLO" value="DETALLES DEL ERROR!!"/>
            <property name="message" expression="get-property('ERROR_MESSAGE')"/>
            <property name="code" expression="get-property('ERROR_CODE')"/>
            <property name="detail" expression="get-property('ERROR_DETAIL')"/>
            <property name="exception" expression="get-property('ERROR_EXCEPTION')"/>
         </log>
       <payloadFactory>
       <format>
         <ns:MyResponse xmlns:ns="http://services.samples">
           <ns:Error>Execution Error</ns:Error>
         </ns:MyResponse>
       </format>
     </payloadFactory>
         <header name="To" action="remove"/>
         <property name="RESPONSE" value="true"/>
         <property name="NO_ENTITY_BODY" scope="axis2" action="remove"/>
         <send/>
      </faultSequence>
   </target>
   <description/>
</proxy>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you use default http passthru transport or NIO ?

Comment: Are you in this case : https://wso2.org/jira/browse/ESBJAVA-2986

Comment: Yes we are using pasthrou. About your second comment I'm not in this case, thanks anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with this fault sequence:
Steps:

1. Create my response message.
2. Use the enrich mediator to store the body in property OK.
3. Create a fault message.
4. Override the body with the property OK using the enrich mediator.

   ```
   <payloadFactory>
       <format>
           <ns:getQuoteResponse xmlns:ns="http://services.samples">
               <ns:return xmlns:ax21="http://services.samples/xsd">
               <status>ERROR</status>
               </ns:return>
           </ns:getQuoteResponse>
       </format>
   </payloadFactory>   
   <log level="full">
      <property name="MESSAGE" value="Mensaje despues del payloadFactory"></property>
   </log>  
   <enrich>
      <source clone="true" type="body"></source>
      <target action="replace" type="property" property="OK"></target>
   </enrich>       
     <makefault version="soap11">
       <code xmlns:soap11Env="schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" value="soap11Env:EdnpointTimeout"/>
       <reason value="timeout fault"/>
       <role/>
     </makefault>
   <enrich>
       <source type="property" clone="true" property="OK"/>
       <target type="body"/>
   </enrich>   
   <log level="full">
      <property name="MESSAGE" value="Mensaje despues del enrich"></property>
   </log>          
   <send/>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

When I run this proxy this is what I get as the response and the console log. Were you expecting something like this?

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
   <soap:Body>
      <ns:MyResponse xmlns:ns="http://services.samples">
         <ns:Error>Execution Error</ns:Error>
      </ns:MyResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>

INFO - LogMediator To: /services/StockQuoteProxy.StockQuoteProxyHttpSoap12Endpoint, WSAction: urn:mediate, SOAPAction: urn:mediate, MessageID: urn:uuid:44da8426-00fc-442a-b4e9-1a9a1dd948f2, Direction: request, FALLO = DETALLES DEL ERROR!!, message = Error connecting to the back end, code = 101503, detail = Error connecting to the back end, exception = null, Envelope: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"><soap:Body></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: Hi Nadeeshaan. Are you using WSO2 ESB 4.8.1? In 4.9.0 that´s the right response, but not in 4.8.1.

Comment: Hi Jorge, I am using 4.8.1 . If you are getting a soap fault message then this  issue is a possibility. And this has been fixed in ESB 4.9.0

Comment: Hi Nadeeshaan, this issue it´s replicated only with a timeout at the endpoint, I used SOAPUI with a sleep(12000) script to simulated this timeout. with others errors or with ESB 4.9.0 work fine.

Comment: Hi Jorge, Did you try this one https://www.mail-archive.com/dev@wso2.org/msg55013.html as suggested in the [dev] mailing list.